# mysql select as alias from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these 2 queries that I would like to combine into one big query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ac, SUM(Views) AS vc FROM tableA
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS mc FROM tableB
```

could'nt find anything on that topic, is it even possible?

Comment: Do you have any common columns?

Comment: Nothing prevents you to execute both queries, having the latter one executed as a subquery.

Comment: @N.B. can you give an example on how to do that?

Comment: Can you share those columns so that we can join them for you.

Comment: @webdeskil - the answer with subqueries is provided so try that one out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do in way using three subquery :

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA) AS ac,
(SELECT SUM(Views) FROM tableA) AS vc,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB) AS mc
```

*This is not very elegant solution, but should do what you need.*

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'tableA' as tablename, COUNT(*) AS count, SUM(Views) AS sum FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT 'tableB' as tablename, COUNT(*) AS count, 0 AS sum FROM tableB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that returns `SELECT COUNT(*) AS mc FROM tableB` and use it in table  A

```
  CREATE FUNCTION Func1() RETURNS INTEGER
  BEGIN
     DECLARE Temp INTEGER;
     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO Temp FROM tableB;
     RETURN IFNULL(Temp, 0);
  END;

  SELECT COUNT(*) AS ac, SUM(Views) AS vc, Func1() as mc FROM tableA
```